# Javascript: shown single data instead of multiple data from a row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to shown the `CSV` data which I get,to shown the output as below:

```
Price: 955.99
EPS: 29.59
Date : 7/14/2017
```

However, I get the output as below:

[image]

It shown in a row, separate with `col0`,`col2`,`col4`.

- Price is `col0`
- EPS is `col2`
- Date is `col4`

**yahooStock.js**

```
angular.module('app').factory('yahooStock',function($http){
  //yahoo query api  
  var yqlUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
  //historical api queryied by yql..
  var historicalUrl = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv';
  //template to put query params into
  var queryTemplate = _.template("select * from csv where url='" + historicalUrl + "?s=<%= symbol %>&f=<%= code %>'");

  function _request(symbol,code){
    return $http({
      method:"GET",
      url: yqlUrl,
      params: {q: queryTemplate({symbol:symbol,code:code}), format: 'json'}
    }).then(function(response){
      console.log('response',response.data);
      return {data:response.data.query.results.row};
    });

  }

  var factory = {
    getYahooData: function(symbol){
        return _request(symbol, 'l1,e,d1');},
};

  return factory;

});
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module("app",['ionic']).controller("mainCtrl",function($scope,yahooStock){
  yahooStock.getYahooData('GOOG').then(function(response){
    $scope.data = response.data;
  });
});
```

**.html**

```
<ion-content has-header="true">
        <p>Price: {{data}}</p>
        <p>EPS: {{data}}</p>
        <p>Date: {{data}}</p>
        <!-- our list and list items -->
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="stock in stocks">
            {{stock.title}}
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
```

I have attached the plunker link.

https://plnkr.co/edit/4bxI8Qd8ftVfaE4D7veN?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p>Price: {{data.col0}}</p> //col0 is price
<p>EPS: {{data.col2}}</p> // col2 is EPS
<p>Date: {{data.col4}}</p> //col44 is Date
```

//col1 and col3 are null, if they not relevant remove them.

Comment: How to remove col1 and col3?